# "There is a book on table on which we have four flowers"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

"There is book on table on which we have four flowers". Could you pls tell me whether "On Which" is referring to table or a book itself or both?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the meaning and/or syntax of a badly-written non-idiomatic utterance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meaning is created by context. Yes, this sentence is unclear as it stands. One might guess that it's more likely for flowers to be on a table than on a book, but it's possible for them to be on a book (perhaps the cover is decorated with an image of four flowers).

Fortunately, no one simply walks up to another human, blurts a single sentence, and then walks away. The rest of the context around this sentence is needed to clarify it.

If one is writing rather than reading this sentence, this is a good reason to change it. Even if the context helps, the pattern "There is an X on a Y that has Z on it" can be confusing. It can be easily be helped by other structures like "An X is sitting on a Y that has Z on it," or "An X with Z on it is on a Y."

Note, there are several other problems. We need articles before "book" and "table": "There is **a** book on **a** (or **the**) table." And while "we have" is not wrong, it's a bit odd without a reason for it.

Comment: +1 for "no one simply walks up to another human, blurts a single sentence".

Comment: @JamesK Or a single word. "Blurt! Word! What does that word mean? That's how dictionaries work, right?"

Comment: Inspired logic.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty and power of natural language is that it can express the situation in the question unambiguously, whatever it is:

> There's a book with four flowers on its cover on the table.
>
> On the table there's a book, and also a vase containing four flowers.

Often I get the impression that non-native students of English are learning from textbooks that make it seem that English has a very limited range of expressiveness.